Diagnosing trouble with an Automator run shell script extracting images from a video with FFMPEG
I'm receiving an error in Automator "The action "Run Shell Script" encountered an error:"
My script works perfectly fine when running it in terminal and gives the exact outputs I need - the script selects the video in the folder: "yourvideo.mp4" and then extracts an image every 60 seconds (Theres also a variable script where I can specify the seconds if needed)
But when I run it through automator: "The action "Run Shell Script" encountered an error"
#!/bin/bash

# Input and output directories
INPUT_DIR="/Users/river/Content/FFMPEG/FFMPEG IN"
OUTPUT_DIR="/Users/river/Content/FFMPEG/FFMPEG Out"

# Default interval (seconds per image)
DEFAULT_INTERVAL=60

# Function to display usage information
usage() {
    echo "Usage: $0 -v video_name [-i interval]"
    echo "  -v video_name   Name of the video file in the input directory to process"
    echo "  -i interval     Interval in seconds between each thumbnail (default is $DEFAULT_INTERVAL seconds)"
    exit 1
}

# Parse command-line arguments
while getopts ":v:i:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    v) VIDEO_NAME="$OPTARG"
    ;;
    i) INTERVAL="$OPTARG"
    ;;
    *) usage
    ;;
  esac
done

# Ensure the video name is provided
if [ -z "$VIDEO_NAME" ]; then
    usage
fi

# Set interval to default if not specified
if [ -z "$INTERVAL" ]; then
    INTERVAL=$DEFAULT_INTERVAL
fi

# Check if the specified video exists in the input directory
VIDEO_PATH="$INPUT_DIR/$VIDEO_NAME"
if [ ! -f "$VIDEO_PATH" ]; then
    echo "Error: Video file '$VIDEO_NAME' not found in the input directory."
    exit 1
fi

# Create output directory if it doesn't exist
mkdir -p "$OUTPUT_DIR"

# Get the base name of the video file (without extension)
BASE_NAME=$(basename "$VIDEO_PATH" | sed 's/\.[^.]*$//')

# Create a subdirectory in the output directory with the video file's name
VIDEO_OUTPUT_DIR="$OUTPUT_DIR/$BASE_NAME"
mkdir -p "$VIDEO_OUTPUT_DIR"

# Generate thumbnails at the specified interval and save them as .png
ffmpeg -i "$VIDEO_PATH" -vf "fps=1/$INTERVAL,scale=iw:ih" "$VIDEO_OUTPUT_DIR/thumb%04d.png"

echo "Thumbnails for '$VIDEO_NAME' have been saved to '$VIDEO_OUTPUT_DIR'"
echo "Thumbnail generation complete."


I have checked the directories & file names are correct. I am very new to using Automator, so I dont know if I'm missing something completely...
Automator has full file access too.
Any help would be appreciated.

Are your directories really called IN and Out?

Try using the full path for ffmpeg - Automator's Run Shell Script uses a default environment which does not include any of your $PATH settings.

How do you run it through Automator? What are the results? Is exit 1 causing the error?
